# How could I have two different URLs on the same server?

Tags: php, html, server

Say I want to have websiteA.com as well as websiteB.com on the same server. They won't be sharing any files, is this possible? I'm not looking for a redirect, they're different sites entirely.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it depends on what server you have.

Comment: Have you every tried to google your title...?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Different websites can be discerned by the `HOST` header in the HTTP protocol. Alternatively, using different ports can be used for each website as well.

Regarding the HOST header, each time you enter a website URL in your browser, the request that gets sent includes the host (example taken from Server Fault question linked below):

URL: `http://snoopy.net/doghouse`

Header:

```
GET /doghouse HTTP/1.1
Host: snoopy.net
```

If you're running Apache, you would specify different hosts in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName www.website1.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/websites/website1/www"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName www.website2.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/websites/website2/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Refer to this Microsoft article: [Bind multiple sites on same IP address and Port in SSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl/), as well as the answers to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/106882/how-do-you-have-one-ip-address-and-many-websites) at Server Fault.